# Can't log on to Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: installation

I downloaded Ubuntu 13.10 using Netbootin Cd 5.2 and everything went okay till i tried to log on.  It asked for my Username and password and that went okay but then it asked for (:~$) and i didn't know what to enter after that.  I am really unfamiliar with terminal language.  Please help.   Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by `~$` you mean the shell prompt (the screen should be completely black with grey letters), you can attempt to start the GUI (X windows system) by running

```
startx
```

by entering the above and pressing ENTER.

If it does not work, it probably means the GUI was not installed, in which case you should try installing again or troubleshooting the installation.